# Preventing thread termination from affecting parent process in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, terminate

My goal is to create an event handling infrastructure that will allow for registration of callback functions and calls to such functions based on time. Further, I plan to make the callback handler multithreaded as there are no restrictions on the type of callbacks, so a sequential architecture could cause unwanted blocking.

From my research I found that if a thread experiences undefined behavior and is terminated (.i.e. with SIGSEGV) then the entire process exits - which is obviously undesirable.

The question, then, is what options are there for ensuring thread independence? I do not think `fork`ing is a viable  option in this case since the callbacks are not fully fledged programs, but rather simple routines to do various time-based tasks.

Comment: A thread (or process) isn't terminated when it "experiences undefined behavior". It *may be* terminated by a signal, but in general you cannot expect any particular behavior, which is why it's called *undefined*.

Comment: @EOF, By this I meant the specific case when a thread is terminated with SIGSEGV.

Comment: Undefined behaviour or segmentation violations are signs of programming errors, it's a good thing if such processes are aborted by the OS.

Comment: It's probably gong to be very ugly. You could block `SIGSEGV` in all other threads and register a signal-handler for it that `pthread_exit()`s, but *technically* that's not exactly safe *or* portable.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, Sure, but the calling process is going to be an event handler. I certainly want the thread to be terminated and handled properly - I just do not want the calling process (just the event callback handler) to be terminated due to a malformed callback function.

Comment: Then you need to run callbacks in a separate process, so any programming errors in the callbacks are isolated into a separate process.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I mentioned that in the post. I could certainly do this, but it would complicate things a bit since at this point all callbacks need to be properly formatted programs to execute by `fork` - unless there is something about this option I am unaware of. I would like a thread-based solution but a process-based option is my fallback.

Comment: Wait: The code registering the callback already runs in the same process as the code handling it (let's leave aside the possibility that you `fork()` in between). So, you already have buggy code in your process!? Actually I wouldn't start with code that needs to be treated as buggy in the first place and refuse to try to work around its bugs. Fixing the buggy code would be my first approach, isolating it in a separate process would just be a workaround. Note that you can't isolate it in a thread, because all threads of a process share the same memory space.

Comment: @sherrellbc, _"it would complicate things a bit since at this point all callbacks need to be properly formatted programs to execute by `fork`"_ No they don't, you are thinking of `fork()` + `exec()`, if you just fork before running a callback then you are running _the same_ program, you don't need the callback to _be_ a program. If the callbacks have side-effects you would need to communicate that back to the parent though.

Comment: *"I do not think forking is a viable option"*. On the contrary, forking is the **only** viable option. Threading provides no memory protection, which means that an errant callback function can overwrite memory that the parent thread is using, leaving the parent thread in an unknown, and possibly unrecoverable state. The only way to prevent the callback functions from potentially disrupting the parent is to run them in a separate process.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No. Assume the event handler and callback handler all entirely bug free. Some user will then use this infrastructure to register some callback function to happen at a particular time. When this time has come the event handler code will call the appropriate requested function -- it is *this* function that cannot be assumed as bug-free. What I am asking about is options related to preventing a buggy registered callback from crashing the entire event handling process.

Comment: Re threads vs processes: you can't have it both ways. You can't have a shared address space, file descriptor table etc. by using threads, but also _not_ have shared address space, file descriptor table etc. so that undefined behaviour in one thread doesn't affect the other threads. The way to do that is by process isolation. i.e. separate processes

Comment: @JonathanWakely, D'oh. You're right. It's been a while since I've used `fork`. I think that'll do.

Comment: when a program calls fork(), the new process (child) is still running the exact same code.  A different set of code to run can be accomplished by then calling one of the exec...() family of functions like execvp()   Until then the child is running the exact same code from the exact same location as before the fork()

Comment: Just to clarify, when I wrote "...so you already have buggy code in your process", I wasn't talking about the event handling framework but rather about the callbacks, because in order to call a callback, you must have it loaded into your process.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong.. If you want time-based tasks, I highly recommend you to try semaphores to control thread.

Block thread function like :

```
while(1){
    sem_wait(my_semaphore);
    code_that_needs_to_be_done_in_thread;
}
```

when you need your work in thread to be done just signal it from code whenever you want and howmany times you want:

```
sem_post(my_semaphore);
...
other_code;
sem_post(my_semaphore);
...
```